# How to fix the socket receive timeout error due to Apache Tomcat 7.0?

Tags: java, apache, sockets, tomcat7, marklogic

I am integrating java code inside `MarkLogic` to convert some EBCDIC files to ASCII using `MLJAM`. `Apache Tomcat 7.0` is being used as the server. The code is running fine for small files, but for huge file processing, MarkLogic is throwing an error:

> SVC-SOCRECV: xdmp:http-post("http://10.76.81.81:8080/mljam/mljam/local/eval", adminadmin) -- Socket receive error: wait 10.78.14.16:63085-10.76.81.81:8080: Timeout (decodeResponseLine1)

As per my understanding, I need to increase the `socket receive timeout period` for the Apache server. Please guide with the steps as how to do it if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably MarkLogic application server's socket receive timeout: https://docs.marklogic.com/admin-help/xdbc-server

To adjust that, go to the admin server on port 8001. In your case I guess it's http://10.76.81.81:8001. Find the XDBC Server for port 8080 and open its "Configure" tab. Look for "request timeout" with the hint text "The request socket recv timeout, in seconds.". It's probably set to the default value, 30 seconds. You'll know best what the new value ought to be, but I'd try doubling it to 60 seconds. Change the value and click on the "OK" button at the top or bottom of the form.

You can also do this using the https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:appserver-set-request-timeout API function.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I have tried increasing all the timeout limits in MarkLogic. It's not working out.